# JSF 2.0 + Primefaces richtext editor

Tags: dependency-injection, jsf-2

```
<p:editor value="#{editorBean.value}"  widgetVar="editor" width="686"
height="390" language="en" align="center">
</p:editor>
```

Following is my rich-text editor bean picked up from primefaces

```
@ManagedBean(name = "editorBean")
@SessionScoped
public class EditorBean {
    private static final String MANAGED_BEAN_NAME = "editorBean";
    private String value;
    public static EditorBean getCurrentInstance() {
        return (EditorBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get(MANAGED_BEAN_NAME);
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Apart from this I have another bean say A. I have a method inside A that populates a HTML table. What I want is when the user opens the editor, it should be pre-populated with that HTML table data and of course the changes should get reflected into (String: value). Therefore, you can say that I am trying to tie up both the values together. I think it needs to be done with DI but somehow its not working. If someone can guide or quote an example, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is rewrite your `getValue()` method to pick up the value from bean `A`.
And yes, the reference to your A bean should come from DI:

```
//injecting a reference to A
@ManagedPropery(value="#{A}") //or whatever is the name of your bean
private A beanA;

public void setBeanA(A beanA) {
    this.beanA = beanA;
}
```

Or, with CDI, just:

```
@Inject private A beanA
```

Finally, your `getValue` method

```
public String getValue() {
    return beanA.getValue()
}
```